# React custom functional component button to do form submit

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom component `RedirectButton`, which is implemented with `<button>` with  additional routing function provided by `react-router-dom` V5.

The following code won't trigger the `handleSubmit`, why?

```
return <div className="import-workspace box">
        <div style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column"}}>
            <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h1>Import Your Space</h1>
                <InputText ref={spaceIdRef}
                           label="space-id" init={spaceId}
                           onChange={value => setSpaceId(value)}/>
                <InputText ref={mapIdRef}
                           label="map-id" init={mapId}
                           onChange={value => setMapId(value)}/>
                <InputText ref={roomsRef} area
                           label="rooms" init={rooms}
                           onChange={value => setRooms(value)}/>
                <RedirectButton text="Start Discrimination" style={{background: "lightgreen"}}
                                to="/workspace-generator"
                                formRef={formRef}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and if I changed the `<RedirectButton>` to simply `<button>test</button>` then the `handleSubmit` will be called, why?

---

```
import {Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";


const RedirectButton = ({text, to, style, onClick}) => {
    const { pathname } = useLocation()
    const { display, justifyContent, ...rest } = style

    return <Link to={to? to: pathname}
                 onClick={onClick}
                 style={{ textDecoration: "none", display, justifyContent }}>
        <button style={{ ...rest }}>
            {text}
        </button>
    </Link>
}

export default RedirectButton
```

Comment: The type of the button is `submit`?

Comment: Please provide the code for `RedirectButton `

Comment: And I have discarded this way of redirecting my among pages. Now I use `<Redirect to="...">` and states.

Answer (score 1):

> and if I changed the  to simply `<button>test</button>` then the handleSubmit will be called, why?

By default, in browsers other than Internet Explorer, `<button />` has a type of "submit" which when wrapped inside a `<form />` element will submit the form.

> The following code won't trigger the handleSubmit, why?

The parent `<Link />` component intercepts the mouse or keyboard event and prevents the event propagating down to the `<button />` element

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type="submit"` to the `<button>` element:

```html
<button style={{ ...rest }} type="submit">
   {text}
</button>
```